# Решение системы уравнений в программе Matlab

Tags: matlab

Не могу решить систему уравнений с получением двух значений.
Начальные данные:

```
>> D=2.6;
>> P_p=0.075*10^6;
>> t_c=100;
>> alpha=45;
>> c=1.3*10^(-3);
>> s=8*10^(-3);
>> s_k=8*10^(-3);
>> phi=1;
>> sigma=162*10^6;
>> sigma_k=1.3*sigma;
>> E=1.99*10^11;
>> mu=0.803;
>> R=D/2;
>> beta=((3*(1-mu^2))^0.25)/((R*(s-c))^0.5);
>> beta_k=((3*(1-mu^2))^0.25)/(((R*(s_k-c))/cos(alpha))^0.5);
>> Q=P_p*R/(2*cot(alpha));
```

А дальше начинается веселье...
Создаю функцию с уравнениями:

```
function f = sides(x)
f(1) = (((2-mu)*R^2*P_p)/(2*E*(s-c)))-((2*beta*R^2*Q)/(E*(s-c)))+((2*beta^2*R^2*x(2))/(E*(s-c)))-(((2-mu)*R^2*P_p)/(2*E(s_k-c)*cos(alpha)))-((2*beta_k*R^2*(x(1)-Q))/(E*(s_k-c)))-((2*beta_k^2*R^2*x(2))/(E*(s_k-c)*cos(alpha)));
f(2) = ((2*beta^2*R^2*x(1))/(E*(s-c)))-((4*beta^3*R^2*x(2))/(E*(s-c)))-((3*R*P_p*sin(alpha))/(2*E*(s_k-c)*cos(aipha)^2))-((2*beta_k^2*R^2*(x(1)-Q))/(E*(s_k-c)*cos(alpha)))-((4*beta_k^3*R^2*x(2))/(E*(s_k-c)*cos(alpha)^2));
end
```

И далее пытаюсь решить...

```
x=[90000 2160];
x=fsolve('sides',x,options.({1000 100000}));
```

А в ответ получаю вот это:
Argument to dynamic structure reference must evaluate to a valid field name.
Может кто нибудь знает где ошибка...? =(

Comment: Что такое `options` и что должно означать `options.({1000 100000})`?

Comment: он требовал диапазон значений, без него отказывался что-либо делать

Comment: даже точнее он хотел видеть эту запись, а значение options ({...}) только примерно понимаю... написала так, как он с меня требовал в ошибке...

Comment: `options` это должна быть какая-то структура с дополнительными параметрами для `fsolve`. Вы пытаетесь получить из этой структуры (кстати, существует ли она, не понятно. Вы привели полный текст программы?) поле с именем `{1000 100000}`. И получаете ошибку, что логично, поскольку таких полей (с такими именами) не бывает

Comment: С данной структурой ранее работать не приходилось...) Да, полностью текст ввела, до данной ошибки. Тогда что же он от меня мог хотеть, когда писал в ошибке, что недостает options  и требоват ввести:
Error in fsolve (line 230)
            fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});

Caused by:
    Failure in initial objective function evaluation. FSOLVE cannot continue.
Данная ошибка вылезает, если применяю более знакомую запись: x=fsolve('sides',[9000 2160]);

Comment: Думаю, что вместо `E(s_k-c)` должно быть `E*(s_k-c)`

Comment: да, это уже нашла. но картина все та же

Comment: Ещё `alpha` вместо  `aipha`